# java program to check duplicate value from a given string

Tags: java

I got a question states that, "we will give you a string ex:Most of the people are living in apartments and they are rich too. In this given string we have to remove "are" and we have to display the rest things...

I don't know what to do???

Comment: I would refrain from asking most homework questions online. it will bite you in the butt in the future

Comment: at least give a try before you actually ask it here

Answer (score 2):

By simply using : `"Most of the people are living in apartments and they are rich too".replaceAll("are","");`

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

use

```
"Most of the people are living in apartments and they are rich too".replaceAll("are","")
```